# Will the ban message be lifted if I give good answers?

Tags: support

I have fixed my questions, and now I don’t see where to fix. So, now I started to try to be helpful and sometimes I got some upvotes, does earning upvotes will make the ban message be lifted?

I ask only out of curiosity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Maybe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

But, it'll probably take a while unless it turns out you're really, really good at answering questions.

Not that this should discourage you from answering where you can, as best as you can. Just don't expect it to have an instant effect on your ability to ask.

As always, the most effective way to lift the ban is to improve your existing questions.

Comment: I have already improved, now I don’t know what to improve...